# How to generate a matplotlib animation using an image array?

Tags: image, matplotlib, animation

So my problem is generating an animation from the list img_array. The code above that is basically used to get an image from the folder, annotate it and then save it into the array. Was wondering if anyone would have any suggestions on how to convert the images in the image array into an animation. Any help is appreciated! TIA.

I tried FFmepg and what not but none of them seem to work. I also tried videowriter in OpenCV but when I tried to open the file I get that this file type is not supported or corrupt.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
import trackpy as tp
import pims
import pylab as pl


##########
pixel_min=23
min_mass=5000
Selector1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11]
##########

frames = pims.ImageSequence('/Users/User/Desktop/eleventh_trial_2/*.tif', as_grey=True)

f1 = tp.locate(frames[0], pixel_min,minmass=min_mass)
plt.figure(1)
ax3=tp.annotate(f1,frames[0])
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.hist(f1['mass'], bins=20)
ax.set(xlabel='mass', ylabel='count');



f = tp.batch(frames[:], pixel_min, minmass=min_mass);

#f = tp.batch(frames[lower_frame:upper_frame], pixel, minmass=min_mass);
t=tp.link_df(f,10,memory=3)
##############
min_mass=8000#12000 #3000#2000 #6000#3000
pixel_min=23;
count=0
img_array = []


for filename in glob.glob('/Users/User/Desktop/eleventh_trial_2/*.tif'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img2 = io.imread(filename, as_gray=True)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(img)




    #ax=pl.text(T1[i,1]+13,T1[i,0],str(int(T1[i,9])),color="red",fontsize=18)

    T1=t.loc[t['frame']==count]
    T1=np.array(T1.sort_values(by='particle'))
    for i in Selector1:
        pl.text(T1[i,1]+13,T1[i,0],str(int(T1[i,9])),color="red",fontsize=18)
        circle2 = plt.Circle((T1[i,1], T1[i,0]), 5, color='r', fill=False)
        ax.add_artist(circle2)


count=count+1
img_array.append(fig)

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, img_array, interval=50, blit=True,repeat_delay=1000)
```

When I run this I don't get an an error however I can't save the ani as tried in the past either using OpenCV videoWriter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around although not the most efficient one. I saved the figures in a separate directory using os and plt.savefig() and then use ImageJ to automatically convert the sequentially numbered and saved figures into an animation. It ain't efficient but gets the job done. I am still open to more efficient answers. Thanks